# Akka Streams - jump over FlowShape

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have the following Graph.

At the `inflateFlow` stage, I check if there is already a request processed in DB. If there is already a processed message, I want to return `MsgSuccess` and not a `RequestProcess`, but the next `FlowShape` won't accept that, it needs a `RequestProcess`. Is there a way to jump from `flowInflate` to `flowWrap` without adding `Either` everywhere?

```scala
GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val flowInflate = builder.add(wrapFunctionInFlowShape[MsgRequest, RequestProcess](inflateFlow))
  val flowProcess = builder.add(wrapFunctionInFlowShape[RequestProcess, SuccessProcess](convertFlow))
  val flowWrite = builder.add(wrapFunctionInFlowShape[SuccessProcess, SuccessProcess](writeFlow))
  val flowWrap = builder.add(wrapFunctionInFlowShape[SuccessProcess, MsgSuccess](wrapFlow))

  flowInflate ~> flowProcess ~> flowWrite ~> flowWrap

  FlowShape(flowInflate.in, flowWrap.out)
}

def wrapFunctionInFlowShape[Input, Output](f: Input => Output): Flow[Input, Output, NotUsed] = {
  Flow.fromFunction { input =>
    f(input)
  }
}

//check for cache
def inflateFlow(msgRequest: MsgRequest): Either[RequestProcess, MsgSuccess] = {
  val hash: String = hashMethod(msgRequest)
  if(existisInDataBase(hash))
    Right(MsgSuccess(hash))
  else
    Left(inflate(msgRequest))
}

def convertFlow(requestPorocess: RequestPocess): SuccessProcess = {}//process the request}
def writeFlow(successProcess: SuccessProcess): SuccessProcess = {}//write to DB}
def wrapFlow(successProcess: SuccessProcess): MsgSuccess = {}//wrap and return the message}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define alternative paths in a stream with a partition. In your case, the [`PartitionWith`](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/api/akka-stream-contrib/current/akka/stream/contrib/PartitionWith.html) stage in the [Akka Stream Contrib](https://github.com/akka/akka-stream-contrib) project could be helpful. Unlike the [`Partition`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Partition.html) stage in the standard Akka Streams API, `PartitionWith` allows the output types to be different: in your case, the output types are `RequestProcess` and `MsgSuccess`.

First, to use `PartitionWith`, add the following dependency to your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-contrib" % "0.8"
```

Second, replace `inflateFlow` with the partition:

```
def split = PartitionWith[MsgRequest, RequestProcess, MsgSuccess] { msgRequest =>
  val hash = hashMethod(msgRequest)
  if (!existisInDataBase(hash))
    Left(inflate(msgRequest))
  else
    Right(MsgSuccess(hash))
}
```

Then incorporate that stage into your graph:

```
val flow = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val pw = builder.add(split)
  val flowProcess = builder.add(wrapFunctionInFlowShape[RequestProcess, SuccessProcess](convertFlow))
  val flowWrite = builder.add(wrapFunctionInFlowShape[SuccessProcess, SuccessProcess](writeFlow))
  val flowWrap = builder.add(wrapFunctionInFlowShape[SuccessProcess, MsgSuccess](wrapFlow))

  val mrg = builder.add(Merge[MsgSuccess](2))

  pw.out0 ~> flowProcess ~> flowWrite ~> flowWrap ~> mrg.in(0)
  pw.out1 ~> mrg.in(1)

  FlowShape(pw.in, mrg.out)
})
```

If an incoming `MsgRequest` is not found in the database and is converted to a `RequestProcess`, then that message goes through your original flow path. If an incoming `MsgRequest` is in the database and resolves to a `MsgSuccess`, then it bypasses the intermediate steps in the flow. In both cases, the resulting `MsgSuccess` messages are merged from the two alternative paths into one flow outlet.